# probabilistic behaviour

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to understand what 'probabilistic behaviour' in a 'deterministic model' means.

I am reading this paper http://www.ulb.ac.be/sciences/use/publications/JLD/16.pdf but i find myself unable to interpret the words 'probabilistic behaviour'

How would one explain it in layman terms?

Comment: The model in the paper is not deterministic.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained. One should not have to read some off-site content to know what it is about.

Comment: @artem the model in this paper is not deterministic , apologies. This is a paper I was referring to for understanding what probabilistic behaviour means ...

Comment: @Did thank you for the suggestion. Will follow that on future posts.

Answer (score 0):

Sees to me that the authors assume that ants are unable to give or receive exact directions to a food source. This leads to ants interpreting the direction information wrongly. And this process of making mistakes is modeled as a random event because there is know way to define deterministically how they make these mistakes. I guess this is true for most mistakes even while I type I may make typing errors and they are distributed randomly in the text.

But it seems that these mistakes leads to finding more or new food sources where there are multiple food sources around the first discovered food source. Therefore in such cases the errors in communication are an advantage.